# Deleting blocks of variable text in TextPad using Regex

Tags: textpad

I want to delete chunks of text in a single text file that Start with "Education" and end with "tanks" and have variable data in between.

Any suggestions?

Comment: so you want to delete the text something like **"Education sdfasdfsa tanks"** this?

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression I believe you want to use is as simple as:
`education.*tank`

I downloaded TextPad, but for some reason when I did a "Search" with this regular expression it would work.  But when I did the same search with the "Replace" function it "could not find it".

I got it to work in Notepad++, though. Just click Search -> Replace (Ctrl+H), and then enter the expression `education.*tank` and then nothing (or a space) in Replace. From there you can use "Find Next" to see if the matches are correct and hit "Replace All" from there.

Those are the steps for Notepad++; if the Replace function works for you in TextPad the steps are similar

Answer (score 0):

1. Click the icon or hit F8 to open the Replace dialog box.

   Type 'education.*tanks' (without the quote marks) in the "Find what:" box.

   Leave the "Replace with:" box blank.

   Uncheck the "Match case" box.

   Check the "Regular expression" box.

   Click "Replace All".

This works for me in tests.

I think the previous answer is essentially right, but neglected checking the RegEx box.